# DataFrame get rows using index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am trying to find a way that gets the row of a dataframe using index that has the same result as using data_file.iterrows(). I tried the following code, but they are not indentical. Is there any way to do this?
Thanks!

```
for row in data_file.iterrows():
    print(row == data_file.iloc[0])
    print(row)
    print(data_file.iloc[0])
    break
```

Comment: You should really be saying `for ind, row in data_file.iterrows():` The iterator gives you a tuple of index, row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corresponding series value is on index1, does that help?

Docs:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

> DataFrame.iterrows()[source]
>
> Iterate over DataFrame rows as (index,**Series**) pairs.

```
print(row[1] == data_file.iloc[0])
```

---

**Another solution:**

```
for ind, row in data_file.iterrows():
```

Comment: Thanks! but why it is row[1]?

Comment: @CongYang Because it is returned as a pair where you are looking for the 2nd element [1]. This: Iterate over DataFrame rows as (index,Series) pairs.

Comment: Because you should really be saying `for ind, row in data_file.iterrows():` The iterator gives you a tuple of index, row

Comment: @smci Yeah well I agree. However I did link to the docs and the phrase: `Iterate over DataFrame rows as (index,Series) pairs.`

Comment: (Anton vBR, I was addressing that to the OP)

Comment: @smci Yes and I was merely commenting that I agree with you!

Answer (score 2):

Because iterrows returns a tuple consisting of the index of the row and the row itself and iloc the row.

```
print(type(row))
<class 'tuple'>
print(type(pl0.iloc[0]))  
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
print(type(row[1]))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

You may use python's ability to unpack tuples:

```
for index, row in data_file.iterrows():
```

Why are you not using iloc directly, anyway? Using iterrows is not recommended, because of its negative performance impact.